# Memory leak/consumption in Hubs due to large messages?

Tags: iis, rabbitmq, signalr

I'm currently trying SignalR and RabbitMQ in order to round-robin / load balance json webservice queries and I'm having troubles with the memory consumption by one of the application when it processes large (~ 300 - 2500 kb) messages.

I have a IIS server hosting a web application (named "Backend") that needs to query an another web application (name "Pricing") also hosted by a IIS server.
In order to keep a connection alive with my RabbitMQ server, I developped console application that are connected to Backend and Princing using SignalR.

So when Backend needs to query Princing, it asks its console to publish the message in the queue and the console attached to Pricing takes the message and give it to Pricing (with Invoke<> method). When Pricing finished its job, it asks its console to publish the reply message and the console attached to Backend takes it and give to Backend.

To sum up : 
[Backend] -> [Console] -> [RabbitMQ] <- [Console] <- [Pricing]

And I have 2 Pricing taking messages from their console from the RabbitMQ queue.

This setup is to replace a traditionnal webservice query between the 2 IIS and benefit from the advantages of RabbitMQ (load balancer and asynchronous call in a micro/web services architecture)

I added

```
  GlobalHost.Configuration.MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize = null;
```

in Startup.cs in both IIS in order to accept large messages.

When I take a look at Pricing's memory consumption in Windows Task Manager, it quickly grows from 500Mb to 1500Mb (in 5 minutes, dealing with neverending queries from Backend to test the setup).

I tried something else by writing the queries content in files in a shared folder and just publishing the name of the file in RabbitMQ's messages and the memory consumption of Pricing (with of course a code modification to load the file) doesn't move and stays around 500Mb.

So it seems that it has something to do with the message length that my console passes to the IIS.

I tried to disconnect the console from the IIS Hubs because I thought that it will maybe free some memory but nope.

Does anyone experienced this issue of memory consumption by large messages into Hubs ? How can I check if there's indeed a memory leak in my application ?

What about using SignalR and RabbitMQ in web/micro services environment ? Any feedback ?

Many thanks,

Jean-Francois

```
.NETFramework : 4.5
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR : 2.4.1
```

Comment: Use a memory profiler to actually check the memory usage please. That can easily tell what might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found out that I could limit the number of messages kept in the hub, which seems to keep the memory down.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the version of SignalR I use (.NetFramework) allows to tune the number of messages per hub per connection kept in memory.
I fixed it to an arbitrary 50 in Startup.cs

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 50;
```

Its default value is 1000, meaning (if I understood it clearly) that IIS keep a circular buffer of 1000 messages in memory. Some of the messages were weighting 2.5Mo meaning that the memory used could go up to 2500Mo per connection.

As my IIS only has one connection (its console) and doesn't need to keep track of messages (as it works as webservice), it seems that 1000 messages is way too much.

With the limit of 50 messages, the memory used by the application in Windows Task Manager stays put (around 500Mo).

Is there any flaw in the way I'm using it ?

Thanks !